# what is the inclusion map for $Y$ to $Y$ x $Y$?

Tags: homological-algebra, homotopy-theory

I am studying homotopy and homology and one map we have been using is the left and right inclusion maps $i_L$, $i_R$, for example from the space $Y$ to the cartesian product $Y$ x $Y$. Whilst I understand that, for example with the left inclusion map, that the left factor in the cartesian proudct is just a replica of the value taken from $Y$, what happens on the right?

I guess what I am asking is what is the ? in $i_L: x \rightarrow (x,?)$

Comment: For _homotopy_ purposes, at least, it can be any fixed element of $Y$. Different choices lead to different-but-homotopic maps.

Comment: SO I choose it? I sort of assumed it was the base point, but wasn't certain?

Comment: x @Jack: If $Y$ is a _pointed_ space, choosing the base point is natural and might well be part of the definition in that case.

Comment: ahh I see, thank you so much. I am trying to show that if $Y$ is a H-space and $X$ is a pointed retract of $Y$ then $X$ is a H-space, struggling though!!

Answer (score 0):

This is defined in the category of pointed spaces by the map:

$$(Y,y_0) \to (Y\times Y,(y_0,y_0))$$